# in bash how to print all variable names beginning with "A" followed by one or more [[:alnum:]]?

Tags: bash

For filenames is possible thanks to "pathname expansion"

```
ls ./A[[:alnum:]]*
```

I would like to write a bash script in order to print all variable names beginning with "A" and followed by one or more alphanumeric characters, like

```
echo "A[[:alnum:]]+"
```

How can I accomplish this, if possible by specifying a character class?

Comment: Note in pathname expansion aka globbing `*` means any number of _any_ char (like `.*` in a regexp); your `ls` command would include `AB@%()`

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple, I have ever used (but in the moment overlooked):

```
set | grep -Ee "\<A[[:alnum:]]+"
```

or

```
env | grep -Ee "\<A[[:alnum:]]+"
```

Yet nevertheless I am interested if there is a way by bash itself, without grep.

Comment: Both of those also include variables whose _value_ contains A followed by at least one alphanumeric, at the beginning or after any special char other than underscore, regardless of name. Try instead `grep -Ee '^A[[:alnum:]]+='`. `env` only includes _exported_ variables, which is not all shell variables as asked, although it might be what you want and _should_ have asked.

Answer (score 1):

To answer of Mahim, Dec 20 2022 19:30

Many thanks. I was not aware of the new bash parameter expansion

```
${!prefix*}
${!prefix@}
```

Manpage bash says:
Names  matching prefix.  Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix, separated by the first character of the IFS

This is the key to a solution based only on bash.

Yet your other explanation I cannot follow. The "!" in this command is not related to regex.

Now I was able to develop a solution which uses only bash. It is given in the next lines.

These are two variables for tests in this example:

```
declare A_notfollowedbyalnum=1
declare Afollowedbyalnum=1
```

The code is:

```
WE_prefix="A"; WE_IFS_saved="$IFS"; IFS=$'\n'; eval WEx=\${!"$WE_prefix"@}; IFS="$WE_IFS_saved"; for WEx_x in $WEx; do if [[ "$WEx_x" =~ $WE_prefix[[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then WEy_x="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"; printf '~%s~\n' "$WEy_x"; fi; done;
```

The output is:

```
~Afollowedbyalnum~
```

Regards

Comment: You don't need to fart with IFS; variable names can never contain any whitespace (or glob char). Just `for i in ${!A*}; do if [[ $i =~ A[[:alnum:]]+ ]]; then echo $i; fi; done`